# Como ejecutar un useEffect al hacer scroll en una parte especifica?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un contador automatico pero quiero que este se ejecute solamente al llegar a una parte en concreto de la pagina, intento llamar la funcion con el evento on scroll de un div pero no funciona

```
useEffect(() => {
    const incrementCount = () => {
      const countOne = 300;
      const countFour = 5;

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (counterOne < countOne) {
          setCounterOne(counterOne + 1);
        }
      }, 5);

      const countTwo = 1000000;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (counterTwo < countTwo) {
          setCounterTwo(counterTwo + 1000);
        }
      }, 1);

      const countThree = 2000;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (counterThree < countThree) {
          setCounterThree(counterThree + 10);
        }
      }, 10);

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (counterFour < countFour) {
          setCounterFour(counterFour + 1);
        }
      }, 500);
    };
    incrementCount()
  }, [counterOne, counterTwo, counterThree, counterFour]);
```

Aca en esta parte quiero llamar la funcion incrementCount, si pudiera llamar la funcion o el useEffect en el contenedor CountersDiv me funcionaria

```
CountersDiv onScroll={incrementCount() o el useEffect}>
      <div className="counter1">
        <span>{counterOne}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="counter2">
        <span>{counterTwo}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="counter3">
        <span>{counterThree}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="counter4">
        <span>{counterFour}</span>
      </div>
    </CountersDiv>
```

Comment: A modo de alternativa: Lo de detectar cuando el elemento está en pantalla yo lo he hecho con IntersectionObserver te dejo una guía (por si te interesa) https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-detect-if-element-is-in-viewport-intersection-observer-api/. También el efecto contador lo he hecho solo con css houdini aquí otro ejemplo https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/